# Find directory content using a string contening full path of many files with a sql request

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge databases containing 200K to ~1M files paths (these are all files saved on a hubic server).

I'm developping an application which print a tree of these dirs and files to allow user to select the files they want to download from the server.

Problem : when I click my "+" button to show a directory content, I have to parse all my table and check if each path belong to my dir.

This takes way too much time. (8s per directory on the smallest server)
How should I do to minimize this ? Is there a way to keep my paths alphabetically sorted so I can avoid parsing the all table ?

Thanks in advance,
José Todeschini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should index your path (or even better make it the primary key) and search like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM     mytable
WHERE   path LIKE '/var/public/a/b/c/%'
```

Note that this should be a string constant, including the percent sign, otherwise the index will not be used.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the primary key, but since every path exists only one time it can be a unique index. Should result in the same performace

Comment: LIKE "/var/%" will give me all files contained in /var/ even in all sub-leveled directories. I need only the files directly in /var/ and the sub dirs.
Is it possible to do LIKE "/var/% 'no-/' " for files ? And how should I do for sub-dirs ?

Comment: @Markus: if it's not a primary key, additional primary key lookup is needed.

Comment: @Jose: you should then keep the directory name, also indexed, along with each file and search by equality. It can be a hash, not the name itself, so that it takes less space and the searches are faster.

Comment: @Quassnoi Since he is using an already existing database, there propably is an primary key defined. So yeah, if there is none currently then he can use the file path. If there already is one he can use a unique index.

Comment: @Jose: if you need a list of subdirs, you better off store the directories too, not just files. But again, seems like you're reimplementing a filesystem in mysql. Why don't you just use `readdir` and similar?

Comment: @Quassnoi : This database is build by a software developed in c/c++ who update these files on distant server. So i have to add another fields named directory name in database and when this soft add the path files also add the directory path ? If it's the only solution to make my code efficient, i should take some lessons of c/c++.

Comment: The application that i develop is used to programm routines in the crontab for the soft developed in c/c++ that uploading file from NAS to an hubic server or recovering a file. My api will be also used to download important file uploaded from hubic server to my NAS in using the c++ soft. C++ soft create a database named hubicobject with these tables : id, name, md5, bytesize. So i have to do with this database to build my tree.

Comment: @jose: right, except that you better store sha256(path) or any other hash than the path itself

Comment: I didn't have build this c++ soft, and it's hard for me to perform these modification because it's make a long long time that i didn't had developed in c++. I'll try to do my best and really, thanks you for all your advice.

Comment: @Jose: you can do all this on the database side, using triggers or cron scripts